# Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$, and $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. If $aH=bK$, prove that $H=K$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$ and $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. If $aH=bK$, prove that $H=K$.

My attempt: we know that $aH=bH$ if $a\in bH$ or $a^{-1}b\in H$. I think that these properties will be used in the solution, but I cannot understand how they will be used since we not know if $a$ and $b$ are part of any subgroup.

I thought of proving somehow that $aH=H$ and $bK=K$ so we could show $H=K$, but again I am stuck at the fact that I do not know if $a$ belongs to $H$ or not.

What should be my next steps?

Comment: *Hint*: prove that $a^{-1}b\in H\cap K$.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry I couldn't get it to work :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $ae=a \in aH$, it follows that $a\in bK \implies aK=bK=aH$. Now, multiply by $a^{-1}$  both sides and you have $H=K$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

$e$ is in both $H$ and $K$ so $ae=bk_1$. Similarly for other cases. Then try to show the same thing common between both in terms of $a$ and $b$. Then from equality, you get whatever you wanted to prove.

Comment: From here I get $a=bk_1$ and $b=ah_1$, which yields that $ab^{-1}=k_1$ and $a^{-1}b=h_1$. What do i do now?

Comment: What is relations with 2 element you have found?

Answer (score 0):

see that $ae=a∈aH$, so $a∈bK$ because $aH=bK$ then $a=bk_{1}$ so, applying inverse. $a^{-1}a=e=a^{-1}bk_{1}$, then and given that $K$ is subgroup $k_{1}$ has inverse to $a^{-1}b$ in $K$, so $a(a^{-1}b)∈aK$ then $b∈aK$ of this that $aK=bK=aH$ Now, multiply by $a^{-1}$ both sides and you have $H=K$.